# I want to travel to a Schengen area country, which one issues visas more quickly?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am living in the UK with a permanent ILR. I hold a Pakistani passport.

I want to travel to some Schengen area countries for holiday. Which consulate issues the quickest visa and what is an easy way to get it?

Also, do I have to buy a travel ticket before applying?

Comment: How fast a visa can be issued depends on a lot of things, most notably how  busy the authorities tht should issue it are, and how simple your case is.

Comment: First, choose your destination. Then you will know which consulate you must apply to.

Comment: @MichaelHampton The OP seems have fairly flexible plans. Suppose someone wants to spend about three days each in several different countries. They could pick country X, spend four days there but three in each  of the others, and make X the first one they visit. X would then be the correct consulate for their application.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan or indeed someone wants to spend a week on holiday in a single Schengen country but doesn't much care which one.

Comment: If you've lived in the UK at least five years, and had ILR for at least one year, you may be able to [apply for British citizenship](https://www.gov.uk/becoming-a-british-citizen/check-if-you-can-apply). After you obtain a British passport you may travel the EU as of right (and even with Brexit it's likely to remain visa-free in future).

Comment: As a Pakistani national, I can tell you that the easiest, smoothest experience I have had with visas was from the Netherlands ... although this was before they outsourced their operations to VFS. You have to **reserve** a ticket, hold a confirmed hotel reservation, provide proof of funds to cover your trip, proof of health insurance for the Schengen zone, and proof of ties to your domicile (usually, this is provided via proof of employment). The process takes 15 days, but if this is your first time, it may take longer. The first time, you are given a very restrictive visa.

Answer (score 3):

Countries which rely on tourism significantly, and which did not experience any attacks, would likely to be the "easiest" to get a visa. For example Spain and Italy. Holding a Pakistani passport might still be a problem though due to current situation, expect higher scrutiny and be ready to present your case both at the embassy and at the passport control.

For "quickest" you have to check with particular consulate. Many Central/Eastern European Schengen countries will have much shorter queues (i.e. you can just walk in without appointment), but their nearest embassy/consulate might be quite far from where you live.

Expect your first visa to be single entry, and to be issued for the exact number of days you present your itinerary for. And yes, for a tourist visa you need to bring the tickets as well as a lot of other things. Requirements are the same for all Schengen countries.

Comment: The only way to get *the facts* here would be to apply at the same day to several different embassies in UK using Pakistani passport, and this is not possible, since you have to submit your passport with any applications.

Comment: My experience was the opposite - the countries which have significant tourism typically have very efficient visa procedures, their clerks are experienced in spotting errors in applications/missing docs (so you won't get a call in a week to bring another needed paper), and they rarely have a backlog. Chinese visas in US, for example, are routinely issued next day, while for a Myanmar visa you might wait for 3+ weeks despite much lower number of applicants.

Comment: Not just that, it also has to be for this guy's unique circumstances (Pakistani passport with UK residence); just because I know several people who had quick turnarounds at certain Shenghen countries embassy/consulate in UK, this doesn't mean this would apply to him. And Embassies do issue visas - so does Myanmar Embassy in DC (they don't even have another consulate in US), or American Embassy in Moscow (they do have two more consulates in Russia, but the Embassy issues visa too in its consular division).